# EXSLT: No more DTM IDs are available

Tags: xml, xslt, xalan, exslt

I've been searching for an answer to this problem all day long.
I'm creating a stylesheet for a moderate-sized XML document (~1.5MB, ~1000 elements), which is giving me a lot of trouble. It's about creating an event-time line graph for different processing plant equipments.
The XML is generated through the SAP MII QueryTempalte thingy, and is in an /Rowsets/Rowset/Row-format. All this data is processed and stored in a local node-set, in a /Equipments/Equipment/Event format.
This node-set is then processed into HTML, and then rendered in the browser.
Now, I'm starting to run into some trouble. I can easily pull data for the past 5 days, which result in ~900 rows of data from MII, and is processed to my node-format, resulting in just under 900 rows. But the second i hit 1017 rows fetched from MII, the stylesheet will only render about half-ways, and then stops and the "No more DTM IDs are available" exception.
Now, the MII server only runs JDK 1.5.x, and I've read, that that might be a problem - only thing is, I can't do anything about that.
So now I'm asking here: Is there a way to optimize my code?? I've attached some links for my XSL and a sample XML.

XSL: http://pastie.org/1566517
Samlpe XML: http://pastie.org/1566522

Now, the sample XML might not yield any "fun" visual results, and won't be able to replicate the error. But if anyone could spot an obvoius optimization, I'd love to know :)
I've been thinking, that it would be nice to replace/move the calculations for startOffset, endOffset, etc, but i can't figure out how.

Hope someone can help me! :)

Comment: http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/faq.html#faq-N10340 says the issue only occurs with a very old version of Xalan. Even if you are not able to change the JDK version you might be able to use an up-to-date version of Xalan from Apache, instead of using the one built-in the JDK. And there are other XSLT processors implemented in and usable with Java, like Saxon, so you could try them on your sample data and stylesheet and check whether they perform better.

Comment: The problem is, that it's impossible to figure out what version of Xalan is running - and if I'm even using it. When i try adding the xalan-namespace to my xsl, the processor won't render it. Also, the JDK is "SAPsk", which means that I have no chance of installing new things or modifing it in any way :(

Comment: I have had this bug many times because of JDK 1.4 using that very old version of Xalan, so you should really try to find out which version you are using. I don't remember finding a workaround for the bug... What do you mean by "the processor won't render it" ?

Comment: What i mean by that is, that if I try to process too large amounts of data, the XSL simply stops half-way through the HTML rendering. It just outputs '<div style="----' as the last part of html. I know that it's running JDK 1.5.0.53, with Xalan 2.7.1, so it's just getting more and more confusing. Earlier, i tried getting Oxygen (xsl debugger) to run through the JDK provided by SAP, but it refused. So obviously, SAP has had their fingers way down the JDK, making it even harder to debug :(

Comment: Hi Thor, did you solved this issue?

Comment: Hi, I don't remember, sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Know this question is old but just hit the same question myself, for those who also find this issue looks like there is a SAP Note detailing a JVM patch which may resolve this:

Note#1604623

https://websmp130.sap-ag.de/sap(bD1lbiZjPTAwMQ==)/bc/bsp/spn/sapnotes/index2.htm?numm=1604623

One of the fixes in the note is:

> Improved resource consumption for XSLT transformation. We fixed a
>   resource leak in the XSLT processing that will result in error
>   "DTMException: No more DTM IDs are available" for complex XSLs using
>   (recursive) templates. The reason for the problem is, that
>   intermediate results of the processing step are stored in DTMs and the
>   number of DTMs is limited to 65536.
>
> With this change, there is a new system property
>   "com.sap.jvm.xsltc.enableResourceOptimization". If this property is
>   set to "true", the XSLT compiler will release intermediate results and
>   therefore will need less resources. Processing of complex XSLs should
>   be possible. Note that this system property is not set per default.

Comment: How can I set "com.sap.jvm.xsltc.enableResourceOptimization" to "true" if I don't have this  <SAP_install_dir>/<system_name>/<instance_name>/j2ee/configtool ??? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

### A Followup

We also encountered this problem with a different application, the basis of the error is the same.  As alluded to above the fundamental problem is a limitation of the [*xalan*, Apache project](https://xalan.apache.org/xalan-j/) for processing *xslt* documents.  The limitation, though triggered rarely, results from exhausting the maximum number of 65535 (16 bits worth of) DTM ids.  In the above application, this is avoided, apparently, by using a resource allocation efficiency feature in SAP, but this will be inapplicable to other applications such as the one we were are using.

#### Changing Xalan

In summary, the 65K DTM id limitation has been around for a while (ca 2003), was patched, and then lost the patch in the *2.7* branch.  The current, latest version of 2.7.2 has this problem.  At its most basic level, a document id is a 32-bit integer. The fix is a source code change that increases the number of bits set aside for DTM.  A more thorough discussion can be viewed [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/xalan-j-users@xml.apache.org/msg04890.html).  The suggested hack is to change the number of node-bits to 12 thus increasing that for DTM to 20 increasing total DTM to 1048576.  The steps are

- download [xalan source](http://apache.mesi.com.ar/xalan/xalan-j/source/)
- unpack and modify src/org/apache/xml/dtm/DTMManager.java by modifying the line that sets `IDENT_DTM_NODE_BITS`.
- build xalan.  You will probably need to install ant and [set the classpath appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730815/unable-to-locate-tools-jar).  The new *jar* will be located in the build directory.
- replace the previous xalan *jar*  with the one that was just built.

Comment: I also have this "No more DTM IDs are available" error. I took the sources, changed IDENT_DTM_NODE_BITS to 20, regenerated xalan.jar but still the same error. Can you send me a xalan.jar that works for you with this error? THANKS!

Comment: I have a question regarding the linked "thorough discussion", the author says «I cannot imagine in my app needing more than 2^12 (4096) document IDs...», what is actually this limit of document IDs? Is it per JVM? Does it mean that Xalan can work on a total of max. 4096 documents at the same time? Imagine a web application which uses Xalan, in every HTTP request Xalan will be used, so that would mean a limit of 4096 parallel HTTP requests at the same time, right?