# Unable to locate tools.jar

Tags: java, apache, ant, build, compilation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to locate tools.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730815/unable-to-locate-tools-jar)

I'm trying to use ant to compile using this command :

```
 ant compile
```

I don't know if the problem comes from my windows 64bit, or by something else. Because I have java Installed in the 64 & 32 prog files.

[image: Java 64 & 32]

I downloaded `apache-ant-1.8.2-bin` and putted it in C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.8.2

I tried to put ant everywhere, I switched also the ENV PATH between java 64 and 32 but everytime I get this error message :

> Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre6\lib\tools.jar

I searched for tools.jar in the ant lib folder, in the java 64 and 32, but no trace of it in the system.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

A JRE doesn't have a tools.jar, you need a JDK. Set your JAVA_HOME and PATH variables so that they point to a JDK, not a JRE.

Comment: Adding "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65" to JAVA_HOME and "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\bin" to PATH did the trick. (jdk1.7.0_65 is for JDK 1.7 Update 65 and can vary)

Comment: @Munchies actually, it's more elegant to add `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` to path. that way you need to change only one variable when you upgrade

Comment: on Windows try restarting your computer, worked for me after.

Comment: Is Windows the only OS where restarting means you lose your currently open Windows? I just restart the cmd console until I see changes propagated there. Unless of course you've elected to be _elegant_ and some rogue script is overriding your JAVA_HOME path so that it's still pointing at the JRE

Comment: For me, adding JAVA_HOME in the windows classpath/path did not help - rather i had to create a new environment variable - JAVA_HOME within the eclipse and point it to JDK7 - that worked

Answer (score 20):

I had similar issue and got solved by doing following ,

1) set JAVA_HOME as C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\

2) ANT_HOME as F:\ant\apache-ant-1.8.4-bin\apache-ant-1.8.4

3) add both to 'path ' in system variables

Comment: Is there a reason why 1) ends with "\" and 2) doesn't?

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure that you are pointing to JDK and not a JRE. For example, you should set JAVA_HOME as "C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.6.0_26" and have %JAVA_HOME%\bin in your system path.

Comment: In my case the variable `CLASSPATH` pointing to `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib` was missing, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26640589/2518971

Answer (score 4):

I had to copy C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\lib\tools.jar to C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext

Thanks anyway.

Comment: You should not do such a thing. A JRE is a JRE and a JDK is a JDK. Don't mix the two, or you'll get strange, non-reproducible behaviour

Comment: I have the jdk and jre in my %PATH%. you think I should remove the jre ?

Comment: I would even suggest removing all of Java installs on your dev machine except for single JDK you will be using :) Unless some of existing product installs don't depend on existing JREs.

Comment: Caution: IN SOME CASES YOU MUST REMOVE THE JRE PATH FOR IT TO WORK.

Answer (score 3):

tools.jar comes with JDK, but what happens in your case it looks for it within /Java/jre6. Change JAVA_HOME env var to one of your JDK home.