# Missing tools.jar file

Tags: java, ant

Yes, I read other posts here about the same thing. I made sure to install the JDK and not the JRE. I installed jdk-7u45-windows-x64 on my Win7 machine but there is no tools.jar file.

Is there some other Java SDK that I need to download and install?

I'm trying to run Ant.

Comment: tools.jar is usually in lib directory in jdk. Did you look there?  Have you installed ant already?  What error do you face when you try to run `ant` ?

Comment: Check that Ant is using the expected jdk by running `ant -diagnostics`

Comment: Ensure you have set the [JAVA_HOME](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html) environment variable to the JDK root.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676107/unable-to-locate-tools-jar?rq=1

Comment: Ant -diagnostics shows that Ant is expecting to find tools.jar in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib but I looked in that lib folder and tools.jar is not in there...but you're saying it shold be in the jdk java path?

Comment: My JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin

Comment: Ahhh tools.jar is in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib so that means my Java_Home is set wrong, it's set to bin and should be set to lib...I will change that and see if that now will work...

Comment: I had to copy the tools.jar from the C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib location to the C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib location and Ant is finally working...thanks guys...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tools.jar is located in jdk_home/lib

Comment: Except that sometimes it is not, hence this error even though the JDK installation is recognized. Likely a non-clean previously executed uninstallation process.

Comment: @Koenigsberg what have you done to solve the error then?