# How to change maven java home

Tags: maven, java

I want to change maven java home which is open jdk with sun jdk. How can I do it ?

```
root@ak-EasyNote-TM98:~# mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_24, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: tr_TR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.2.0-34-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Edit:
```

So sorry. I forgot to write the below code :

```
root@ak-EasyNote-TM98:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

My java home default path is sun jdk already. But maven java home has pointed openjdk. I want to fix it only for maven.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you are in Linux, set JAVA_HOME using syntax `export JAVA_HOME=<path-to-java>`. Actually it is not only for Maven.

Comment: For those who do not know where oracle-java is installed to, you can find this by first running `which java` which will tell you which binary of java is being called. In my case it was `/usr/bin/java`. At this point you can run `readlink -f /usr/bin/java`, which for me yielded `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java` ergo `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/`

Comment: Does it work only for the current Terminal window or does it change system properties?

Comment: @BCqrstoO's help in one line: `export JAVA_HOME=\`readlink -f \\`command -v java\\`\``

Answer (score 59):

I am **using Mac** and none of the answers above helped me. I found out that maven loads its own JAVA_HOME from the path specified in: `~/.mavenrc`

I changed the content of the file to be: `JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home`

For **Linux** it will look something like:
`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre`

Comment: Also works on Linux; it will look something like `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre`.

Comment: I've added the Linux part to the answer. I didn't test it. Please tell me if it works.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. My very stupid self of 4 years ago caused me this pain that you solved. :)

Comment: Or better yet, just remove `.mavenrc` (or at least the line that specifies `JAVA_HOME`), and maven will default to your normal `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 1000 times. Wasted way too many hours trying on this only to find this solution. Thank you!

Comment: For me, the mavenrc was located in `/etc/mavenrc`

Answer (score 20):

The best way to force a specific JVM for MAVEN is to create a system wide file loaded by the mvn script.

This file is `/etc/mavenrc` and it must declare a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable pointing to your specific JVM.

Example:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

If the file exists, it's loaded.

Here is an extract of the `mvn` script in order to understand :

```
  if [ -f /etc/mavenrc ] ; then
    . /etc/mavenrc
  fi

  if [ -f "$HOME/.mavenrc" ] ; then
    . "$HOME/.mavenrc"
  fi
```

Alternately, the same content can be written in `~/.mavenrc`

Comment: Also, a warning to RHEL CentOS users: have a look at the mvn script, because it may differ from the code snippet above. In my case it has a nasty ". /etc/java/maven.conf" line between the two ifs, so if I insert a JAVA_HOME variable into /etc/mavenrc it gets overwritten in the next step. I had to edit /etc/java/maven.conf (and hope that upgrading the maven package won't overwrite my changes in the future).

Comment: you saved 3 days of mine... thanks !

Answer (score 16):

If you are dealing with multiple projects needing different Java versions to build, there is no need to set a new `JAVA_HOME` environment variable value for each build. Instead execute Maven like:

```sh
JAVA_HOME=/path/to/your/jdk mvn clean install
```

It will build using the specified JDK, but it won't change your environment variable.

Demo:

```
$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.0
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.6, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-72-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

$ JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_201 mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.0
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_201, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /opt/jdk1.8.0_201/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-72-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

$ export | grep JAVA_HOME
declare -x JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
```

Answer (score 5):

Great helps above, but if you having the similar environment like I did, this is how I get it to work.

- having a few jdk running, openjdk, oracle jdk and a few versions.
- install apache-maven via yum, package is apache-maven-3.2.1-1.el6.noarch

Edit this file /etc/profile.d/apache-maven.sh, such as the following, note that it will affect the whole system.

```
$ cat /etc/profile.d/apache-maven.sh
MAVEN_HOME=/usr/share/apache-maven
M2_HOME=$MAVEN_HOME
PATH=$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH
# change below to the jdk you want mvn to reference.
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/
export MAVEN_HOME
export M2_HOME
export PATH
export JAVA_HOME
```

Answer (score 4):

Even if you install the Oracle JDK, your `$JAVA_HOME` variable should refer to the path of the JRE **that is inside** the JDK root. You can refer to [my other answer  to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31025631/795158) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem. If the JAVA_HOME was showing the JDK root, then Surefire has taken JDK/bin/java as JAVA_HOME for its forked JVM, which is false. Saved my day. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Appears to be a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/21131/how-to-correctly-remove-openjdk-and-jre-and-set-the-system-use-only-and-only-sun#answer-21137 assuming that you are using Ubuntu.

The key is to use the command `sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun`.  Any commands that rely on `javac` will be affected and not just Maven.

Answer (score 2):

Just set JAVA_HOME env property.

Answer (score 1):

I have two Java versions on my Ubuntu server 14.04: `java 1.7` and `java 1.8`.

I have a project that I need to build using `java 1.8`.

If I check my Java version using `java -version`

I get

```
java version "1.8.0_144"
```

But when I did `mvn -version` I get:

```
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
```

### To set the mvn version to `java8`

I do this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/
```

Then when I do `mvn -version` I get:

```
Java version: 1.8.0_144, vendor: Oracle Corporation
```