# JAVA_HOME and PATH are set but java -version still shows the old one

Tags: java, linux, environment-variables, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint Cinnamon 14. I have set the `$JAVA_HOME` and `$PATH` environment variables in `~/.profile` as follows:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/aqeel/development/jdk/jdk1.6.0_35
export PATH=/home/aqeel/development/jdk/jdk1.6.0_35/bin:$PATH
```

I then did `source ~/.profile` to make the proper changes.

When I execute `java -version` command to check the active java version, it shows the default (already installed open-jdk) java version. How can I override the default open-jdk with the one I downloaded?

**UPDATE:**

`which java` says /usr/bin/java

`$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version` says 'Permission Denied'

`sudo $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version` (asks for password, then) says Command not found

but `cd $JAVA_HOME/bin`, and `ls` shows that it is right directory.

Comment: may be reverse the PATH defenition `export PATH=$PATH:/home/aqeel/development/jdk/jdk1.6.0_35/bin`

Comment: if you are still in the same session then you'll have to reload profile `source ~/.profile`

Answer (score 71, accepted):

While it looks like your setup is correct, there are a few things to check:

1. The output of `env` - specifically `PATH`.
2. `command -v java` tells you what?
3. Is there a `java` executable in `$JAVA_HOME\bin` and does it have the execute bit set? If not `chmod a+x java` it.

I trust you have `source`'d your `.profile` after adding/changing the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`?

Also, you can help yourself in future maintenance of your JDK installation by writing this instead:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/aqeel/development/jdk/jdk1.6.0_35
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Then you only need to update one env variable when you setup the JDK installation.

Finally, you may need to run `hash -r` to clear the Bash program cache. Other shells may need a similar command.

Cheers,

Comment: I see, no file in the $JAVA_HOME/bin directory is marked as executable. Please tell me what other files I have to mark as executable? (Also please see the question I have edited it) Thanks a lot

Comment: See my bullet 3 above. `chmod a+x *` in the `bin` directory will probably do the trick. Also read `man chmod` and something on permissions on unix/linux in general.

Comment: Ok, after doing `chmod a+x *` in the `bin` directory, the `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java` -version outcome is received, but `java -version` is still the old default one.

Comment: Close the shell, open a new one, make sure the `PATH` is set correctly, try again.

Comment: When exporting the PATH, place the $PATH itself as last parameter. Otherwise you will probably still reference the old one.

Answer (score 20):

**`update-java-alternatives`**

The `java` executable is not found with your `JAVA_HOME`, it only depends on your `PATH`.

`update-java-alternatives` is a good way to manage it for the entire system is through:

```
update-java-alternatives -l
```

Sample output:

```
java-7-oracle 1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
java-8-oracle 2 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Choose one of the alternatives:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle
```

Like `update-alternatives`, it works through symlink management. The advantage is that is manages symlinks to all the Java utilities at once: `javac`, `java`, `javap`, etc.

I am yet to see a `JAVA_HOME` effect on the JDK. So far, I have only seen it used in third-party tools, [e.g. Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752519/how-to-change-maven-java-home).

Comment: [update-alternative command not found](https://askubuntu.com/a/93713/915076) helped

Answer (score 12):

If you want to **use JDKs downloaded from Oracle's site**, what worked for me (using Mint) is using ***update-alternatives***:

1. I downloaded the JDK and extracted it just anywhere, for example in */home/aqeel/development/jdk/jdk1.6.0_35*
2. I ran:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /home/aqeel/development/jdk/jdk1.6.0_35/bin/java 1
   ```

   **Now you can** execute `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and **choose your java version**.
3. This doesn't set the **JAVA_HOME variable**, which I wanted configured, so I just added it to my ~/.bashrc, including an `export JAVA_HOME="/home/aqeel/development/jdk/jdk1.6.0_35"` statement

Now, I had **two JDKs downloaded** (let's say the second has been extracted to */home/aqeel/development/jdk/jdk-10.0.1*).

How can we change the JAVA_HOME dynamically based on the current java being used?

My solution is not very elegant, I'm pretty sure there are better options out there, but anyway:

4. **To change the JAVA_HOME dynamically based on the chosen java alternative**, I added this snippet to the ~/.bashrc:

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=$(update-alternatives --query java | grep Value: | awk -F'Value: ' '{print $2}' | awk -F'/bin/java' '{print $1}')
   ```

Finally (this is out of the scope) **if you have to change the java version constantly**, you might want to consider:

5. Adding an **alias** to your *~./bash_aliases*:

   ```
   alias change-java="sudo update-alternatives --config java"
   ```

(You might have to create the file and maybe uncomment the section related to this in *~/.bashrc*)

Comment: It seems the last character should be removed, no? sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /home/aqeel/development/jdk/jdk1.6.0_35/bin/java 1`

Comment: right, the command is `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /home/aqeel/development/jdk/jdk1.6.0_35/bin/java 1`, just fixed that thanks for the heads up @CleberJorgeAmaral

Comment: The only correct answer on the Internet

Answer (score 4):

> $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version says 'Permission Denied'

If you cannot access or run code, it which be ignored if added to your path. You need to make it accessible and runnable or get a copy of your own.

Do an

```
ls -ld $JAVA_HOME $JAVA_HOME/bin $JAVA_HOME/bin/java
```

to see why you cannot access or run this program,.

Comment: Ooops, It was not marked as executable (as @Anders R. Bystrup pointed out in his answer). After doing `chmod a+x *` in the `bin` directory, the `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java` -version outcome is received, but `java -version` is still the old default one.

Comment: try calling `hash -r` to cause the shell remove it's remembered locations.

Answer (score 4):

When it searches for java it looks from left to right in path entries which are separated by : so you need to add the path of latest jdk/bin directory before /usr/bin, so when it searches it'll find the latest one and stop searching further.

i.e. PATH=/usr/java/jdk_1.8/bin:/usr/bin:..... and so on.

then initialize user profile using command:  source ~/.bash_profile

and check with: [which java]

you'll get the right one.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

- export JAVA_HOME=put_here_your_java_home_path
- type export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH (ensure that $JAVA_HOME is the first element in PATH)
- try java -version

Reason: there could be other PATH elements point to alternative java home. If you put first your preferred JAVA_HOME, the system will use this one.

Comment: ok, this should be accepted as the correct solution, instead of using 3rd party services like sdk and all this is great, that $JAVA_HOME part in the PATH variable is exactly what I have been missing.

Answer (score 2):

check available Java versions on your Linux system by using update-alternatives command:

```
 $ sudo update-alternatives --display java
```

Now that there are suitable candidates to change to, you can switch the default Java version among available Java JREs by running the following command:

```
 $ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

When prompted, select the Java version you would like to use.1 or 2 or 3 or etc..

Now you can verify the default Java version changed as follows.

```
 $ java -version
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way, just remove the symbolic link from "/usr/bin". It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` does not work sometimes. I just deleted JDK 6 and `source`d `.bash_profile`.

Try running this:

```
sudo rm -rd jdk1.6.0_* #it may not let you delete without sudo
```

Then, modify/add your JAVA_HOME and PATH variables.

```
source ~/.bash_profile #assuming you've updated $JAVA_HOME and $PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

In Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon be sure to check **/etc/profile.d/jdk_home.sh** I renamed this file to jdk_home.sh.old and now my path does not keep getting overridden and I can call java -version and see Java 9 as expected. Even though I correctly selected Java 9 in `update-aternatives --config java` this jdk_home.sh file kept overriding the $PATH on boot-up.