# How to set JAVA_HOME path on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, java-home

How can I setup `JAVA_HOME` path without having to set it each time I restart my machine?

I've used the following ways when trying to set JAVA_HOME on my Ubuntu machine:

1) From terminal I've executed the following command:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
```

2) I've edited the `/etc/enviroment` file directly to add `JAVA_HOME` path in it

What's really strange is that if I test `JAVA_HOME` using the `echo` command after an of the above two ways, I can see it is set correctly, but if I restart, logout/ login again or even after working on the machine for a while the `JAVA_HOME` is no more set and I have to set it again using any of the above two ways.

So can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You should ask this on unix.stackexchange.com or askubuntu.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119983/i-have-set-java-home-and-path-variables-but-java-version-still-shows-the-old-on may this help you

Comment: echo 'export JAVA_HOME=`jrunscript -e '"'java.lang.System.out.println(java.lang.System.getProperty("'"java.home"));'"'"\` >> ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I normally set paths in

```
~/.bashrc
```

However for Java, I followed instructions at 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7

and it was sufficient for me.

you can also define multiple java_home's and have only one of them active (rest commented).

suppose in your bashrc file, you have

`export JAVA_HOME=......jdk1.7`

`#export JAVA_HOME=......jdk1.8`

notice 1.8 is commented. Once you do

`source ~/.bashrc`

jdk1.7 will be in path.

you can switch them fairly easily this way. There are other more permanent solutions too. The link I posted has that info.

Answer (score 47):

add JAVA_HOME to the file:

```
/etc/environment
```

for it to be available to the entire system (you would need to restart Ubuntu though)

Comment: it is NOT necessary to update ubuntu, after change the variable execute: *$source /etc/environment* , and done!

Comment: @Chechus you're right, but it would only update the environment of the command-line terminal where you execute `source /etc/environment` for the rest of the processes the environment won't change

Comment: @Sergio Sourcing _/etc/environment_ must never be done. It's not a script file.

Comment: i believe this would be better, as i don't have to define JAVA_HOME each time i boot ubuntu manually