# JConsole location in Linux

Tags: java, linux, jvm, jconsole, java-home

I am trying to run jconsole from my machine but I can't find the location of the .sh . I have tried finding it in different directories and setting JAVA_HOME to the jdk.

```
$which java
/usr/bin/java
$java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.4.1.el6_5-x86_64 u51-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode) 
$whereis java 
java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/lib/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

I looked in /usr/lib/jvm and I found

```
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Apr 23  2013 java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Jan 27  2014 java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Feb  5  2014 java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.51.x86_64
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   21 Feb  5  2014 jre -> /etc/alternatives/jre
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   27 Apr 23  2013 jre-1.5.0 -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.5.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   26 Apr 23  2013 jre-1.5.0-gcj -> java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   27 Feb  5  2014 jre-1.6.0 -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.6.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   37 Feb  5  2014 jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64 -> java-1.6.0-openjdk-    1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   27 Feb  5  2014 jre-1.7.0 -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.7.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   38 Feb  5  2014 jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 -> java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.51.x86_64/jre
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   25 Apr 23  2013 jre-gcj -> /etc/alternatives/jre_gcj
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   29 Feb  5  2014 jre-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/jre_openjdk
```

and in java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.51.x86_64/jre/bin/, I only found

```
[root@portal01 bin]# ll
total 200
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  9536 Jan 14  2014 java
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  9656 Jan 14  2014 keytool
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  9856 Jan 14  2014 orbd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  9688 Jan 14  2014 pack200
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 10984 Jan 14  2014 policytool
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  9648 Jan 14  2014 rmid
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  9656 Jan 14  2014 rmiregistry
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  9688 Jan 14  2014 servertool
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  9896 Jan 14  2014 tnameserv
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 92264 Jan 14  2014 unpack200
```

..even though there are 200 files. How can I find and run jconsole?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jconsole is part of the Java SDK, it appears you only have the JRE installed.

Comment: I did not have SDK installed.

Comment: running Linux MINT 20.2 with openjdk version "11.0.14" 2022-01-18 - I've scoured the internet and can't seem to find the right way to install "Java SDK" to get jconsole myself. Any advice?

Answer (score 6):

You can run jconsole directly from your terminal by running the command jconsole.

reena@IM-1500:~$ jconsole

It will launch java monitoring console dialog.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I tried that as well and I got this message                                                                   -bash: jconsole: command not found

Comment: no it did not run. It give below error.
-bash: jconsole: command not found

Answer (score 3):

From https://serverfault.com/questions/179908/fedora-jconsole-location:

> Try running: yum provides */jconsole
>
> that will tell you what package you need as well as where it's located in the package.

Answer (score 1):

Once you set the path of JDK in Linux then this command execute easily might be you had not included the JAVA_HOME with PATH variable.

plz follow this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119983/i-have-set-java-home-and-path-variables-but-java-version-still-shows-the-old-on)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Java JDK installed in your Linux machine, usually `jconsole` is located at `/usr/bin/` as a symbolic link.

Example from my Linux VM running Centos6

```
$ which jconsole
/usr/bin/jconsole
$ ls -l /usr/bin/jconsole
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 26 Sep  4 10:05 /usr/bin/jconsole -> /etc/alternatives/jconsole
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/jconsole
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 51 Sep  4 10:05 /etc/alternatives/jconsole -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/jconsole
```

But you mentioned you got the a `command not found` error when you typed `jconsole` at the prompt. Can you find if `jconsole` is available in one of the jdk's bin directory?

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin | grep jconsole
```

If yes, then add this in your `PATH` environment variable like so

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin
```

or put this in your `~/.bashrc` if you are using `Bash`.

If `jconsole` is not there, then maybe you need to try another jdk which you have installed or re-install the jdk.

Answer (score 0):

Please install JDK Development Package to get Jconsole