# Is it possible to setup 2 JAVA_HOME in Linux?

Tags: linux, java-home, rhel6

I am using RHEL 6.8. Is it possible to set up a 1.8 server JRE path in JAVA_HOME in Linux when the JDK is 1.7.0_45? I need both of the java versions and two JAVA_HOME.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to handle such things is by using [alternatives](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_alternatives.htm).

Meaning: it is absolutely no problem to have multiple JREs/JDKs on the same system; you just need to **manage** them; and *alternatives* helps with that.

For Redhat, have a look into their [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Installation_Guide/sect-use_alternatives_to_set_default_JDK.html).

Comment: I tried that.. but nothing is showing after entering the command : /usr/sbin/alternatives --config java.. it just comes to the next line as root. I am not getting the alternatives installed as per the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 version but you can use only one at a time or create 2 system user with different profile as mentioned below:

/usr/local/java/
    - jdk1.8.0_60
    - jre1.7.0_60

```
1) vim ~/.profile or vim ~/.bash_profile

2) Add below lines at end. Please check your jdk/jre path and change it accordingly 
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_60
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

3) exit vim editor

4) echo $JAVA_HOME
```

you will require to logout from system and login again.

if you want to switch it to jdk1.8.0_60 then edit the same file ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile and follow the above procedure again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really have two JAVA_HOME environmental variables in the same Linux environment (the env variables are basically key-value entries, thus you can't have to entries with the same key JAVA_HOME).

I suggest the solution I wrote here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50766853/6661361

In few words:

1. Install all your java alternatives:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /home/aqeel/development/jdk/jdk1.6.0_35/bin/java 1`
   ```
2. Add the following snippet to your *~/.bashrc* (or other bash configuration file, depending on the scope you want to use):

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=$(update-alternatives --query java | grep Value: | awk -F'Value: ' '{print $2}' | awk -F'/bin/java' '{print $1}')
   ```
3. Choose you java version with the following command:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config java
   ```

   Your JAVA_HOME should change automatically (just remember to open a new command terminal after changing the java version, or create a script to do it manually).
4. *Optionally*: **if you have to change the java version constantly**, you might want to consider adding an **alias** to your *~./bash_aliases*:

   ```
   alias change-java="sudo update-alternatives --config java"
   ```

(You might have to create the file and maybe uncomment the section related to this in *~/.bashrc*).