# Changed JAVA_HOME and PATH but java version remains the same

Tags: java, bash

I have a Red Hat Linux machine where I am trying to use Java 8.

So I did this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/my/path/to/oracle/jdk/1.8/exec
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
```

However, if I run `java -version` I get `java version "1.7.0_121"`.

I looked at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119983/i-have-set-java-home-and-path-variables-but-java-version-still-shows-the-old-on), but I don't seem to have the same problem.

If I run `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version` I get `java version "1.8.0_72-b15"`, so `JAVA_HOME` does point to Java 8.

`which java` outputs `/usr/bin/java`.

So how can `JAVA_HOME` point to Java 8, while `java -version` points to Java 7?

Comment: Try: `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH`

Comment: what does `ls -l /usr/bin/java` show?

Comment: I tried `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH`, but nothing changes.

Comment: `ls -l /usr/bin/java` shows `/usr/java/default/bin/java`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you did not configured your `PATH` correctly, try `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`:

- Add `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to `$PATH`, not `$JAVA_HOME`, because the full path to `java` is `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java` in the description of question.
- Put your `$JAVA_HOME/bin` in the head of `$PATH`, not the tail, otherwise the old `java` in original `$PATH` will always be found by shell first.

Comment: You might want to add *why* this will help.

Comment: I've added more descriptions :-)

Comment: Default java binary must be managed in Linux using alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but I had a similar problem on `Windows`.

After some research I discovered that a copy of older version of `java.exe` was also put into `Windows`' `system32` folder.

Maybe something similar is happening in your case ... however I cannot tell you which folder to look for on `linux...` may be something like  `/sbin`,`/bin`,`/usr/bin/` etc.

The older version of the file `java.exe` should be in some directory that is on your `path` variable. So, you can try `echo $PATH` to get ideas as where to look.

Also reversing the order `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` (as suggested by others) also could work, as the first version encountered on the `path` would be the new version (`1.8`).

Answer (score 0):

The file `/usr/bin/java` is a symlink. Just change it to link your Java 8 location as follows:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/java
sudo ln -s /path/to/java8/jre/bin/java /usr/bin/java
```

**Notice:** you might want to change, as well, every other Java symlinks to have a consistent version of all your Java tools (e.g. javac, javap, etc)

Comment: default java version must be managed using alternatives, not manually.

Comment: Default Java version can be managed manually or using `alternatives`, the way that fits you best.

Answer (score 0):

Default java binary is managed in Linux using alternatives

```
someuser@linux:~/tmp> /usr/sbin/alternatives --display java | grep 'priority'
/usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk/bin/java - priority 1705
/usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/bin/java - priority 1805
```

Java 8 gets the higher priority. Also, Linux does not use $JAVA_HOME to determine the path to a binary so setting it has no effect in this case.

To set default java version using alternatives refer to this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/121654/how-to-set-default-java-version

Comment: This does not answer OP's question which is how to change from a version of Java to other.