# Setting PATH env on Linux

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I tried installing java on Amazon linux.

I installed jdk 1.8.0 and I changed PATH to .bash_profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/.../jdk1.8.0_192
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

but java -version still returns old java version (1.7.0)

I checked the result was `JAVA_HOME` = `/usr/lib/jvm/jre`

if I check `which java` then the result is `/usr/bin/java`

how to change the java version to the new one?

Comment: Open new console and try again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAVA\_HOME and PATH are set but java -version still shows the old one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14119983/608639). Or, which duplicate do you prefer: [linux how to set "java_home" path site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+how+to+set+%22java_home%22+path+site%3Astackoverflow.com)?

Answer (score 0):

you need to type below command on shell

sudo update-alternatives --config java

It will display all available JRE and you need to type the number which java you want to select(You can perform this for javac also).