# Maven Refuses Java Home Directory

Tags: java, macos, maven

I followed the instructions to point Maven to the appropriate JDK via a `/etc/mavenrc` file detailed here:
[How to change maven java home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752519/how-to-change-maven-java-home)

When I then try to run maven, it fails, citing that the Java home directory is improperly defined because it's a directory.

> mvn --version
>   /etc/mavenrc: line 1: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home: is a directory
>   The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
>   This environment variable is needed to run this program
>   NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

My understanding is that Java_Home is supposed to be a directory. Why is it refusing to use the appropriate directory?

Comment: I think the error message is explicit. Does this directory `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home` contain a folder named `bin` and inside it there are **JDK tools** like `javac` and `javap`?

Comment: It does. Everything is there. I've tried pointing to the /bin directory and I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Mac the `$HOME/.mavenrc` file should contain a JAVA_HOME declaration like in a shell script.

```
ravn$ cat ~/.mavenrc 
JAVA_HOME=/Users/ravn/Downloads/zulu7.22.0.3-jdk7.0.171-macosx_x64
ravn$
```

This is a nice feature which is not very well documented.

Comment: This solved my problem. The .mavenrv file was pointing to a JDK that didn't exist. Pointing it at the correct directory solved the problem.

Comment: I just see now that you are modifying `/etc/mavenrc` which is a global file.  For multi-user systems this is not a good idea for many reasons.  I would suggest using `~/.mavenrc` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and have been trying to solve it for an hour. I have `JAVA_HOME` pointed to the correct jdk location by using the following line but still has this problem.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

How I fix it finally is to paste the same line above to `.mavenrc`