# Unable to locate tools.jar by ant command JAVA_HOME and PATH is set for jdk instead jre

Tags: java, ant, path-variables

I am using windows 7 java installed in Program files and Program Files (x86).
I am getting such error "Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\tools.jar`

```
 I have set path variable to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51;`
 JAVA_HOME `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51;`
```

But I tried `ant -diagnostics` command get java.home is `C:\Programe Files\Java\jre7\`

Comment: Did you set the environment variables locally (to the console session) or via the System Properties dialog?  If you used the System Properties dialog, did you close and re-open the console and try again?  What does `echo %java_home%` display?

Comment: via system properties, and yes I am trying ant command by closing command prompt. `echo %java_home%` display `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51;`

Comment: I hope you set %PATH% to `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`, rather than just to `%JAVA_HOME%` as there are no binaries in `%JAVA_HOME%`, which could lead to what you're seeing

Comment: @KoushikRout Can you attach a screenshot of the output on the console for echo %JAVA_HOME% please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to locate tools.jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730815/unable-to-locate-tools-jar)

Comment: Add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the system variable "path"

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed `Java Development Kit (JDK)` you can find this Jar at the place.

I seems you have installed only `Java Runtime Environment (JRE)`

So if tools.jar is not there at the path `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\`, try placing it manually at the path.It should solve your problem.

Comment: In Program files\Java folder both jdk1.7.0.51 and jre7 folder are there so I think jdk installed properly.

Comment: Manually place tool.jar at C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\

Comment: Yes I manually place tool.jar at proper place it works for me but is this the actual solution or I need to try some other way ?

Comment: Moving tools.jar to the JRE lib folder is definitely not the solution here.

Comment: He has both JDK and JRE installed..And Tool.jar is doesn't exists because of some reason, so I suggested that..Why wont it be a solution if the error goes away by manually placing it there ?

Comment: Perhaps investigate the reason why it isn't there? Your proposal is a workaround, not a solution

Comment: Ok.Then one more try can be add %JAVA_HOME% to start of the PATH variable.

Comment: Now you are guessing. You always add %JAVA_JOME%\bin to PATH anyhow.

Comment: @JavaLearner So what happens if the JDK is re-installed? The problem will exist once again unless someone remembers the manual step to copy the tools.jar file again. Like I say, not a solution, a temporary workaround at best.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

**echo %JAVA_HOME%**:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51`

But ant -diagnostics indicated:

**java.home : `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60`**

The problem is the JAVA_HOME environment variable is pointing to an invalid directory.

In your case, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51` does not exist, so Ant goes looking for the folder itself and I guess pulls the JRE folder first.

The problem is that `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51` does not exist, and so ANT resets the java.home variable to first Java directory that it finds:

C:\Programe Files\Java\jre7\

In my case, I had both of these and it still did not find the correct one:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60`

`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60`

You probably had updated to a more recently version of the JDK, like

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79`