# Cloud computing application using java

Tags: java

I am building a cloud application programmed in Java.

I got this problem:

> Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\tools.jar

I have installed jdk and the folder: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib is existed in my system but the lib: tools.jar is not there.

any idea?

Comment: It seems obvious that tools.jar is expected in the **jre6** folder while your jre installation is a different version and located in the **jre7** folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to locate tools.jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730815/unable-to-locate-tools-jar)

Comment: I know `cloud` might be a popular buzzword right now, but adding it as a tag and in the description when it's not relevant at all doesn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

`tools.jar` is a part of `JDK` not `JRE`.
Please, check your environment variables `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME`.
`JAVA_HOME` should be set to JDK home directory e.g.

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk6
```

`PATH` should contains `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

```
PATH=...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;...
```